# sqldatasource problem

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a listview with an sqldatasource and the link buttons don't get fired up, but if i use as datasource an String array they get fired up. Am i missing something in my code?

aspx page:

```
    <%
    SqlDataSourceArticoleUser.ConnectionString = conn;
    SqlDataSourceArticoleUser.SelectCommand = "SELECT top 10 * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id desc) AS Row, * FROM articole) AS EMP WHERE Row >" + pag + " and username='" + user + "'";
            %>
<asp:ListView ID="ListViewArticoleUser" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceArticoleUser">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <ul>
                        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                    </ul>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonEditArticolEdit" runat="server" Text="edit" CommandName="articoledit"></asp:LinkButton>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonStergeArticolEdit" runat="server" Text="sterge" CommandName="articolsterge"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceArticoleUser" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

aspx.cs page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlDataSourceArticoleUser.DataBind();
        }
    }
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewArticoleUser.ItemCommand += new EventHandler<ListViewCommandEventArgs>(ListViewArticoleUser_EventHandler);
    }
    protected void ListViewArticoleUser_EventHandler(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "articolsterge")
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, remind me to register on that site with a user name of:  '; delete * from articole;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing something... When you use a string array as datasource, you will use the default c# dataadapter, that contains instructions for delete, update and insert.

When you are working with an sql datasource, you must configure how .net will deal with those operations. I can see you just configured the select operation. To have a full functional sqldatasource, I think you must fill other operations.

Check this article to help you with your datasource: http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/sqldatasource.aspx!

Specially this part:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Pubs %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT [au_id], [au_lname], [au_fname], [state] FROM [authors]"
  UpdateCommand="UPDATE [authors] SET [au_id] = @au_id, [au_lname] = @au_lname,[au_fname] = @au_fname, [state] = @state WHERE [au_id] = @original_au_id"
  DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [authors] WHERE [au_id] = @original_au_id"/>
```